# How to format this so that the text does not move with the image

Tags: html, image, format, html-lists

Any help on how I can get my ul to not be changed by the position/size of the image in the body? I have been attempting to do this for quite some time, and this is my first project with coding so I am running into some problems. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   
  <head>
   <base target="_top">
    <style>
    .listStyle {
      font-size:175%;
      text-align:center;
      list-style-type:none;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      padding: 0;
    }
    </style>
  
  </head>
  <body>
    <span><img src="url" alt="YMF Logo" style="float:right;" height="auto";width="100px;margin: 0 auto;"></span>
    <b>
      <u>
<h1 style="position:relative;top:40px;text-align:center;font-size:175;">
Warehouse Quick Links
</h1>
</u>
<div style="position:relative;top:20px;">
  <ul class="listStyle">
    
  <li>
    <a href="url" target="_blank" rel="noreferer noopener"> Outbound Sheet </a> 
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href = "url" target="_blank" rel="noreferer noopener"> Spoils Form </a>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a href = "url" target="_blank" rel="referer noopener"> Check-In Form </a> 
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href = "url" target="_blank" rel="referer noopener"> Amazon Pallet Guide </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href = "url" target="_blank" rel="referer noopener"> Amazon Packaging Guide </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href = "url" target="_blank" rel="referer noopener"> Shipstation </a>
  </li>
    
  <li>
    <a href = "url" target="_blank" rel="referer noopener"> Amazon Seller Central </a>
  </li>

  </ul>
</div>
</b>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the image a style of

```
position:absolute
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

instead of float: right.
It should work

Answer (score 0):

You can using class as follows

```
.myimage{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10;
  right: 0; /* or left: 0; if you want to change */
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zfoscpxe/)**